# Directory.GetFiles in VB 2010 script only take path from C drive

Tags: vb.net, ssis

The SSIS package I create is at C drive

When I use `Directory.GetFiles("C:\")` in script task, I can execute the package successfully.
But When I use path in D drive -> `Directory.GetFiles("D:\")`
Will get following error

Although I can get the package working but still want to use the folder in D drive.

> [Script Task Example] Error: The given path's format is not supported.   at System.Security.Util.StringExpressionSet.CanonicalizePath(String path, Boolean needFullPath)
>      at System.Security.Util.StringExpressionSet.CreateListFromExpressions(String[] str, Boolean needFullPath)
>      at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.AddPathList(FileIOPermissionAccess access, AccessControlActions control, String[] pathListOrig, Boolean checkForDuplicates, Boolean needFullPath, Boolean copyPathList)
>      at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.AddPathList(FileIOPermissionAccess access, String[] pathListOrig, Boolean checkForDuplicates, Boolean needFullPath, Boolean copyPathList)
>      at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission..ctor(FileIOPermissionAccess access, String[] pathList, Boolean checkForDuplicates, Boolean needFullPath)
>      at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1..ctor(String path, String originalUserPath, String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption, SearchResultHandler`1 resultHandler, Boolean checkHost)
>      at System.IO.Directory.InternalGetFileDirectoryNames(String path, String userPathOriginal, String searchPattern, Boolean includeFiles, Boolean includeDirs, SearchOption searchOption, Boolean checkHost)
>      at System.IO.Directory.InternalGetFiles(String path, String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption)
>      at ST_ca574867e60a45e28f879a2dcd18c6c4.ScriptMain.Main()

Answer (score 0):

I find out provide UNC path will work for me.
so instead of Directory.GetFiles("D:\")
Directory.GetFiles("\\[server name]\[folder path]") will allow me successful run the package with folder location at D drive.

I got UNC from folder property->Sharing->Network Path